# How to scan a list of names into an array?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am trying to scan a file of 200 names to scan into a one-dimensional array. Then access them from the array at a later point to pick a winner. However, I am lost with the scanning the names into the array to begin with.  This is what I have so far.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{       
   int size = 200;  
   String [] theList = new String[size]; //initializing the size of the array

  //Scan in all names in file.
  Scanner playerNamesScan = new Scanner(new File("PlayerNames.txt"));

  String names; 
  while(playerNamesScan.hasNextLine())
  {
     names = playerNamesScan.nextLine(); 
     System.out.println(names);   //just to make sure it is scanning in all the names
     System.out.println(theList[0]);  //this gives me null because not in array
  }
```

I am pretty sure this is 100% wrong and think maybe something like an iterator is needed but I am somewhat lost on iterators. Can someone help point me in the right direction or explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Just use `Files.lines().toArray(String[]::new)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to store the `String`s in the array. You can do it by using an index:

```
int index = 0;
while(playerNamesScan.hasNextLine() && index < theList.length) {
    names = playerNamesScan.nextLine(); 
    theList[index++] = names;
    System.out.println(names);   //just to make sure it is scanning in all the names
    System.out.println(theList[0]);  //this gives me null because not in array
}
```

But some (most of the) times you don't know how many elements you need to store. In such cases, it would be better to use a `List` rather than an array. A `List` allows adding elements and resize the data structure used behind the scenes for you. Here's an example:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
Scanner playerNamesScan = ...
while(playerNamesScan.hasNextLine() && index < theList.length) {
    String name = playerNamesScan.nextLine(); 
    names.add(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following;

```
   int size = 3;  
   List<String> nameList = new ArrayList(); //initializing the size of the array

   //Scan in all names in file.
   Scanner playerNamesScan = new Scanner(new File("c:/temp/PlayerNames.txt"));
   while(playerNamesScan.hasNextLine())
   {
      nameList.add(playerNamesScan.nextLine()); 
   }        

   String[] nameArray = nameList.toArray(new String[nameList.size()]);
   System.out.print(Arrays.toString(nameArray));
```